# How Do You "Permanently" Delete An Experiment In Mlflow?

Tags: python, mlflow

Permanent deletion of an experiment isn't documented anywhere. I'm using Mlflow w/ backend postgres db

Here's what I've run:

```
client = MlflowClient(tracking_uri=server)
client.delete_experiment(1)
```

This deletes the the experiment, but when I run a new experiment with the same name as the one I just deleted, it will return this error:

```
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Cannot set a deleted experiment 'cross-sell' as the active experiment. You can restore the experiment, or permanently delete the  experiment to create a new one.
```

I cannot find anywhere in the documentation that shows how to permanently delete everything.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems there is no way to do this via the UI or CLI at the moment :-/

The way to do it depends on the type of backend file store that you are using.

**Filestore**:

If you are using the filesystem as a storage mechanism (the default) then it is easy. The 'deleted' experiments are moved to a `.trash` folder. You just need to clear that out:

```sh
rm -rf mlruns/.trash/*
```

As of the current version of the [documentation](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#mlflow-experiments-delete) (1.7.2), they remark:

> It is recommended to use a cron job or an alternate workflow mechanism to clear `.trash` folder.

**SQL Database:**

This is more tricky, as there are dependencies that need to be deleted. I am using MySQL, and these commands work for me:

```sql
USE mlflow_db;  # the name of your database
DELETE FROM experiment_tags WHERE experiment_id=ANY(
    SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage="deleted"
);
DELETE FROM latest_metrics WHERE run_uuid=ANY(
    SELECT run_uuid FROM runs WHERE experiment_id=ANY(
        SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage="deleted"
    )
);
DELETE FROM metrics WHERE run_uuid=ANY(
    SELECT run_uuid FROM runs WHERE experiment_id=ANY(
        SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage="deleted"
    )
);
DELETE FROM tags WHERE run_uuid=ANY(
    SELECT run_uuid FROM runs WHERE experiment_id=ANY(
        SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage="deleted"
    )
);
DELETE FROM runs WHERE experiment_id=ANY(
    SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage="deleted"
);
DELETE FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage="deleted";
```

Comment: In case anyone is looking for this folder on EC2, it will be in cd ~/./mlruns/ from the root directory

Answer (score 22):

As of mlflow 1.11.0, the recommended way to permanently delete runs within an experiment is: [`mlflow gc [OPTIONS]`](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#mlflow-gc).

From the documentation, `mlflow gc` will

> Permanently delete runs in the *deleted* lifecycle stage from the specified backend store. This command deletes all artifacts and metadata associated with the specified runs.

Comment: It does not work with SQL backend:

    mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: This cli can only be used with a backend that allows hard-deleting runs

Comment: Seems they are working on it by adding parameter `--backend-store-uri <PATH>`: https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#mlflow-gc But when I run it on our sqlite backend I still get `mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Not implemented yet`

Comment: Working with postgres hosted in AWS RDS as of MLflow 1.18.0

Answer (score 14):

I am adding SQL commands if you want to delete permanently Trash of MLFlow if you are using PostgreSQL as backend storage.

Change to your MLFlow Database, e.g. by using: `\c mlflow`
and then:

```
DELETE FROM experiment_tags WHERE experiment_id=ANY(
    SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
);
DELETE FROM latest_metrics WHERE run_uuid=ANY(
    SELECT run_uuid FROM runs WHERE experiment_id=ANY(
        SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
    )
);
DELETE FROM metrics WHERE run_uuid=ANY(
    SELECT run_uuid FROM runs WHERE experiment_id=ANY(
        SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
    )
);
DELETE FROM tags WHERE run_uuid=ANY(
    SELECT run_uuid FROM runs WHERE experiment_id=ANY(
        SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
    )
);
DELETE FROM params WHERE run_uuid=ANY(
    SELECT run_uuid FROM runs where experiment_id=ANY(
        SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
));
DELETE FROM runs WHERE experiment_id=ANY(
    SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
);
DELETE FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted';
```

The difference is, that I added the 'params' Table SQL Delete command there.

Answer (score 4):

Extending [@Lee Netherton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341459/lee-netherton)'s answer, you can use [PyMySQL](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/) to execute those queries and remove all metadata from MLFlow tracking server after deleting the experiment from the MLFlow tracking client.

```
import pymysql

def perm_delete_exp():
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='user',
        password='password',
        db='mlflow',
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        queries = """
            USE mlflow;
            DELETE FROM experiment_tags WHERE experiment_id=ANY(SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage="deleted");
            DELETE FROM latest_metrics WHERE run_uuid=ANY(SELECT run_uuid FROM runs WHERE experiment_id=ANY(SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage="deleted"));
            DELETE FROM metrics WHERE run_uuid=ANY(SELECT run_uuid FROM runs WHERE experiment_id=ANY(SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage="deleted"));
            DELETE FROM tags WHERE run_uuid=ANY(SELECT run_uuid FROM runs WHERE experiment_id=ANY(SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage="deleted"));
            DELETE FROM runs WHERE experiment_id=ANY(SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage="deleted");
            DELETE FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage="deleted";
        """
        for query in queries.splitlines()[1:-1]:
            cursor.execute(query.strip())
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

You can (perhaps should) execute the entire query at once, but I found debugging it easier this way.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the SQL commands above did not work with SQLITE in my case.
Here is the SQL version working with sqlite in a database IDE by replacing the "any" commands with "in":

```
DELETE FROM experiment_tags WHERE experiment_id in (
    SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
    );
DELETE FROM latest_metrics WHERE run_uuid in (
    SELECT run_uuid FROM runs WHERE experiment_id in (
        SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
    )
);
DELETE FROM metrics WHERE run_uuid in (
    SELECT run_uuid FROM runs WHERE experiment_id in (
        SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
    )
);
DELETE FROM tags WHERE run_uuid in (
    SELECT run_uuid FROM runs WHERE experiment_id in (
        SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
    )
);
DELETE FROM params WHERE run_uuid in (
    SELECT run_uuid FROM runs where experiment_id in (
        SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
));
DELETE FROM runs WHERE experiment_id in (
    SELECT experiment_id FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
);
DELETE FROM experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted';
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using S3 as backend store for artifacts and have a EC2 server for tracking**, this is my workaround to delete full experiments 'folders'.
You have to delete the experiment both on the artifact store (S3) and on the backend store (database hosted on EC2)

**Permanently delete experiments via list of experiment ids:**

```
def permanently_delete_experiments_on_mlflow(list_of_experiments_id: list):
    mlflow_client = MlflowClient(tracking_uri=YOUR_EC2_TRACKING_URI)
    commands = []
    for experiment_id in list_of_experiments_id:
        print(f'deleting experiment {experiment_id}')
        os.system(f"aws s3 rm {YOUR_S3_ARTIFACTS_STORE} "
                  f"--recursive --exclude '*' --include '{experiment_id}/*'")
        try:
            mlflow_client.delete_experiment(experiment_id)
        except Exception as e:
            print_red(f'failed to execute mlflow_client.delete_experiment({experiment_id}) \n {str(e)}')
        commands.append(f"YOUR_PATH_TO_DATABASE_ON_EC2{os.sep}database.db{os.sep}{experiment_id} ")
        commands.append(f"YOUR_PATH_TO_DATABASE_ON_EC2{os.sep}database.db{os.sep}.trash{os.sep}{experiment_id} ")
    # format commands to send via ssh to EC2
    commands = f"ssh -i {YOUR_EC2_SSH_KEY_PATH} ubuntu@{YOUR_EC2_IP} rm -r " \
               + ' '.join(commands)
    print('executing on EC2 the following command: \n   ', commands)
    result = subprocess.Popen(commands, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    response, err = result.communicate()
    print('response:', response)
```

Note that for this to work you need to have [AWS CLI installed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html).

It basically runs a shell command from Python that does the trick.
As a side note, the mlflow tracking with EC2 creates 'folders' both on the EC2 database and on S3 named according to the experiment id which contains a 'subfolder' for each run id corresponding to that experiment. The code above relies on this structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you use SQlite, you can permanently delete experiment 42 as follows:

```
mlflow gc --backend-store-uri sqlite:////path/to/mlflow.db --experiment-ids 42
```

Also see [mlflow gc documentation](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#mlflow-gc).

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving this here for the mssql folks who might need this:

```
DELETE FROM mlflow.dbo.experiment_tags WHERE experiment_id in (
    SELECT experiment_id FROM mlflow.dbo.experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
    );
DELETE FROM mlflow.dbo.latest_metrics WHERE run_uuid in (
    SELECT run_uuid FROM mlflow.dbo.runs WHERE experiment_id in (
        SELECT experiment_id FROM mlflow.dbo.experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
    )
);
DELETE FROM mlflow.dbo.metrics WHERE run_uuid in (
    SELECT run_uuid FROM mlflow.dbo.runs WHERE experiment_id in (
        SELECT experiment_id FROM mlflow.dbo.experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
    )
);
DELETE FROM mlflow.dbo.tags WHERE run_uuid in (
    SELECT run_uuid FROM mlflow.dbo.runs WHERE experiment_id in (
        SELECT experiment_id FROM mlflow.dbo.experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
    )
);
DELETE FROM mlflow.dbo.params WHERE run_uuid in (
    SELECT run_uuid FROM mlflow.dbo.runs where experiment_id in (
        SELECT experiment_id FROM mlflow.dbo.experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
));
DELETE FROM mlflow.dbo.runs WHERE experiment_id in (
    SELECT experiment_id FROM mlflow.dbo.experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted'
);
DELETE FROM mlflow.dbo.experiments where lifecycle_stage='deleted';
```