# Is there mlflow REST api to hard delete experiments, runs?

Tags: rest, mlflow, mlops

Mlfow exp delete api does soft delete and when you create experiment with that name, it gives error RESOURCE_ALREADY_EXISTS.

Is there any way to delete experiment permanently through api?
https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#delete-experiment

There is similar question here, [How Do You "Permanently" Delete An Experiment In Mlflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60088889/how-do-you-permanently-delete-an-experiment-in-mlflow)
where answers are to run delete sql queries directly by connecting to backend DB which i want to avoid.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this? It is so frustrating that one cannot delete an experiment completely in sql backends